# Error in projecting a shapefile from CRS of ArcMap to a Proj4 string

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, geometry, rasterio

I am trying to export the outputs of the National Water Model (https://github.com/NOAA-Big-Data-Program/bdp-data-docs/blob/main/nwm/README.md) inside of a basin using Python.

With this code I called the data from AWS:

```
s3_path = 's3://noaa-nwm-retrospective-2-1-zarr-pds/ldasout.zarr' 
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
store = s3fs.S3Map(root=s3_path, s3=s3, check=False)
ldasout = xr.open_zarr(store=store,consolidated=True)
```

Then, this is the outcome:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 122479, y: 3840, x: 4608, vis_nir: 2, soil_layers_stag: 4)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-02-01T03:00:00 ... 2020-12-31T21:00:00
  * x         (x) float64 -2.303e+06 -2.302e+06 ... 2.303e+06 2.304e+06
  * y         (y) float64 -1.92e+06 -1.919e+06 ... 1.918e+06 1.919e+06
Dimensions without coordinates: vis_nir, soil_layers_stag
Data variables: (12/20)
    ACCET     (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    ACSNOM    (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    ALBEDO    (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    ALBSND    (time, y, vis_nir, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 1, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    ALBSNI    (time, y, vis_nir, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 1, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    COSZ      (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    ...        ...
    SNEQV     (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    SNOWH     (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    SOIL_M    (time, y, soil_layers_stag, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 1, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    SOIL_W    (time, y, soil_layers_stag, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 1, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    TRAD      (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
    UGDRNOFF  (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(224, 350, 350), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    Conventions:          CF-1.6
    GDAL_DataType:        Generic
    TITLE:                OUTPUT FROM WRF-Hydro v5.2.0-beta2
    code_version:         v5.2.0-beta2
    model_configuration:  retrospective
    model_output_type:    land
    proj4:                +proj=lcc +units=m +a=6370000.0 +b=6370000.0 +lat_1...
```

Then, I try to reproject the shapefile where is the basin to the same proj4  of the xarray.Dataset using the following code:

```
proj4_string = '+proj=lcc +units=m +a=6370000.0 +b=6370000.0 +lat_1=30.0 +lat_2=60.0 +lat_0=40.0 +lon_0=-97.0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k_0=1.0 +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs'
target_crs = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4(proj4_string)

shapefile_path = 'basins_Lambert_conformal_conic.shp'
basins = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
projected_basin = basins.to_crs(target_crs)

snow=ldasout['QSNOW']
snow=snow.rio.write_crs(target_crs)
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run this line of code:

```
snow1=snow.rio.clip(projected_basin.iloc[[5]].geometry)

ERROR 1: PROJ: internal_proj_identify: Transformation cannot be formatted as WKT1 TOWGS84 parameters
```

This is how the raster and the shapefile look in ArcMap and clearly are not correct:

[image]

I am not sure how to fix it because the proj4_string does not have an equivalent in EPSG CRS. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a geographic transformation? I'm not an expert in Northern Hemisphere CRS but looks to me like you're trying to transform WGS84 to NAD, that would require a transformation to be specified. Is there a NTv2 or TOWGS84 parameter that you should be using?